# Getting count of all children and if any child contains user id in nested hierarchy

Tags: mysql, performance, hierarchy, query-performance

I am trying to create a newsfeed for posts and comments. The user should see:
 1. A latest post in liked group or by a followed user
 2. A post with the latest comment (n-th level) in liked group or latest comment by a followed user
 3. If the comment is on a comment, then n-the level comment, n-1 level comment and the post on which the comment was made, where the comment is in a liked group or by a followed user.
 4. Each post should come only once, in the feed

I am following the nested set model in MySQL for storing comments. The schema for posts and comments is like:

```
**Posts**
id  |  post_text  | user_id  |  group_id   |  created_date

**Comments**
id  |  post_id |  comment_text  | lft  |  rgt   |  created_date
```

For every post created, I insert a row with lft and rgt 0,0. For any comment, the rows after that have adjusted lft and rgt values. For example, a post with a 2 comments, with the first comment having 2 child comments will be like

```
**Posts**
id  |  post_text  | user_id  |  group_id  |  created_date
 1        text        1            1

**Comments**
id  |  post_id |  comment_text  | lft  |  rgt  | created_date
 1        1         comment         0      0
 2        1         comment         1      6
 3        1         comment         2      3 
 4        1         comment         4      5
 5        1         comment         7      8

To get the feed, my query looks like:

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT p.id, p.post_text, c.text
    FROM posts p
    INNER JOIN comments c
    ON p.id = c.post_id
    ORDER BY c.created_date DESC) as sub
GROUP BY sub.id
```

This query takes forever on my table with about 70K rows. In the feed, I also need to show the number of child each feed item row has and if the logged in user has posted a comment on a post/comment or not, i.e. for an item at n-th level, if there exists another item at n+1 level with the logged in user's id.

What is the best way to achieve this? Should I run multiple queries?